# Solving integro-differential Equation with Dirac-Delta Term For Dynamical Analysis

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, integral-equations

I am trying to solve Equation.44 from this paper https://labsites.rochester.edu/agrawal/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/paper_2019_03.pdf
But I am unable to tackle the Integrand term which includes Dirac-Delta term and an additional response function as follows
[image]

[image]

Here I attach my code in MATHEMATICA. Is there any process so that I can check the normalization throughout the program? As the particle number should be 3, I took U_0=1.5. So that after normalization I will get N=3.

```
a = 20;
Cvalue = 0.5;
qvalue = 100;
Nvalue = Sqrt[Cvalue];
Fvalue[ζ_] := 
  Cos[π*qvalue*ζ]^2 + Cvalue^2 Sin[π*qvalue*ζ]^2;
para1 = 12.2*10^-15;
para2 = 32*10^-15;
fR = 0.18;
δ = 0.02;
hR[k_] := (para1^2 + para2^2)/(para1*para2^2)
    Exp[-k/para2] Sin[k/para1];
R[k_] := (1 - fR) DiracDelta[k] + fR*hR[k];
eqs = {I D[u[ζ, τ], ζ] + 
     1/2 D[u[ζ, τ], {τ, 2}] - 
     I*δ*D[u[ζ, τ], {τ, 3}] + 
     Nvalue^2/
      Fvalue[ζ] u[ζ, τ] Integrate[
       R[s] Abs[u[ζ, τ - s]]^2, {s, 0, ∞}] == 0, 
   u[0, τ] == 1.5 Sech[τ], u[ζ, -a] == 0, 
   u[ζ, a] == 0};
sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, u, {τ, -a, a}, {ζ, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 20, "MaxPoints" -> 81, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
DensityPlot[
 Abs[sol[ζ, τ]]^2, {τ, -a, a}, {ζ, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

So, I omitted the Dirac-Delta term and still failed here is the code

```
a = 20; \[Zeta]max = 1; step = 10^-6; d\[Tau] = (a - step)/6 - step;
n = 5;
int[0][\[Zeta]_, \[Tau]_] := 0;
Cvalue = 0.5;
qvalue = 100;
Nvalue = Sqrt[Cvalue];
Fvalue[\[Zeta]_] := 
  Cos[\[Pi]*qvalue*\[Zeta]]^2 + Cvalue^2 Sin[\[Pi]*qvalue*\[Zeta]]^2;
\[Delta] = 0.02;
fR = 0.18;
Do[Itaretion[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{I D[u[\[Zeta], \[Tau]], \[Zeta]] + 
      1/2 D[u[\[Zeta], \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 2}] - 
      I \[Delta] D[u[\[Zeta], \[Tau]], {\[Tau], 3}] + 
      Nvalue^2/Fvalue[\[Zeta]] u[\[Zeta], \[Tau]]*fR*  
       int[i - 1][\[Zeta], \[Tau]] == 0, 
    u[\[Zeta], -L] == u[\[Zeta], L], 
    u[0, \[Tau]] == 1.5*Sech[\[Tau]]}, 
   u, {\[Tau], -L, L}, {\[Zeta], 0, \[Zeta]max}, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 40}}}];
 int[i] = 
  Interpolation[
   NIntegrate[
    Abs[U[i][\[Zeta], \[Tau] - s]]^2*Exp[-s/10^-15] Sin[s/10^-15], {s,
      0, \[Infinity]}], {\[Tau], -a, a, d\[Tau]}, {\[Zeta], 
    0, \[Zeta]max, .2*\[Zeta]max}];, {i, 1, n}]

DensityPlot[
 Itaretion[n][\[Zeta], \[Tau]], {\[Tau], -a, a}, {\[Zeta], 
  0, \[Zeta]max}]
```

Comment: `NDSolve` cannot solve problems involving `DiracDelta`! You have to  approximate for example as a limit.

Comment: You should write down your equations in the question, explain what they describe and clarify your code. If you don't do it I will down vote your question.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Your statement  "NDSolve cannot solve problems involving DiracDelta" does not correspond to reality (see the result of `sol = NDSolve[{f'[x] == f[x] + DiracDelta[x - 1], f[0] == 1}, 
   f, {x, 0, 2}]; Plot[Evaluate[f[x]/.sol],{x,0,2}]`).

Comment: I have tried solving the equation omitting only the Dirac-Delta term in the integration and allowing the h_R(t) term. But still I am unable to do it.@UlrichNeumann@user64494

Comment: I looked in the linked article. It should be noticed that the notation  $\delta(x-x')$ appears (for the first time) in (16) without any description and/or definition . The statement "that the Kernel in Eq. (11) is reduced to the form"  before (16) is unclear to me.

Comment: If it's possible can I get any suggestion of getting a result omitting any one of the terms involved in the integrand (either Dirac-Delta term or h_R(t) term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with using method of lines as [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267884/nonlinear-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-with-periodically-varying-function/267931?noredirect=1#comment668058_267931). First, we note that $\int_{s_1}^{s_2} \delta(s)f(t-s)=f(t)$ for any interval with $s1<0,s_2>0$. But if we take $s_1=0, s_2\rightarrow\infty$  as in a paper, then we have not well defined result

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[s] f[t - s], {s, 0, Infinity}]

Out[]= -f[t] (-1 + HeavisideTheta[0])
```

Therefore the answer depends on how we interpreter `HeavisideTheta[0]`. In numerical model it looks like `HeavisideTheta[0]=RandomReal[]`, or may be 0.5, or may be 0. In our computation we put `HeavisideTheta[0]=0`. Second question is about function $h_R(t)$ normalization. In our computation we use for normalization $T_0=57 fs$. Finally we have

```
a = 20; h = 1/10; grid = Range[-a, a, h]; nn = Length[grid]; 
varu[t_] := Table[u[i][t], {i, nn}]; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, 2, nn - 1}]; fddf2 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], grid, 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]; fddf3 = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[3], grid, 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]; mat2 = 
 fddf2@"DifferentiationMatrix"; mat3 = 
 fddf3@"DifferentiationMatrix"; du2 = mat2 . varu[t]; du3 = 
 mat3 . varu[t];
Cvalue = .5;
qvalue = 100;
Nvalue = 3;
Fvalue[t_] := Cos[\[Pi]*qvalue*t]^2 + Cvalue^2 Sin[\[Pi]*qvalue*t]^2;
T0 = 57(*fs*);
para1 = 12.2/T0;
para2 = 32/T0;
fR = 0.18;
\[Delta] = 0.02;
hR[k_] := (para1^2 + para2^2)/(para1*para2^2) Exp[-k/para2] Sin[
    k/para1];
R[k_] :=(*(1-fR) DiracDelta[k]+fR*)hR[k];
eqs = Table[
   I D[u[i][t], t] + 1/2 du2[[i]] - I*\[Delta]*du3[[i]] + 
     Nvalue^2/ 
       Fvalue[t] ((1 - fR) Abs[u[i][t]]^2 + 
        fR h Sum[
          If[i - s < 1, 0, hR[grid[[s]] + a] Abs[u[i - s][t]]^2], {s, 
           1, nn}]) u[i][t] == 0, {i, 3, nn - 1}];
ic = Table[u[i][0] == Sech[grid[[i]]], {i, 3, nn - 1}]; u[1][t_] := 0;
 u[nn][t_] := 0; u[2][t_] := 0

sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, 0, 1}, MaxSteps -> 10^6, 
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
```

Visualization

```
lst = Table[{{t, grid[[i]]}, Abs[u[i][t]] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 
   1, .01}, {i, nn}]; U = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1]];
Plot3D[U[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> {\[Zeta], \[Tau]}]

DensityPlot[U[t, x], {x, -a, a}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 AxesLabel -> {\[Tau], \[Zeta]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks, Sir. I have a couple of questions. 1. The reason for Multiplying h before summing in eqs. and 2. Addition of "a" in If command. Is there any reason to use the Explicite Rungekutta method?

Comment: This is approximation of  $\int_0^{\infty} h_R(s)|u(\zeta ,\tau-s)|^2ds$ with $ds=h$. Adding `a` allow us to fix `s=0`. No reason it just example of Method.

Comment: Option ` MaxSteps -> 10^6` used for the case with `{t,0,100}`. In a case `{t,0,1}` we can remove all options in `NDSolve`.

Comment: How  "a" is fixing s=0?@AlexTrounev

Comment: Please check that `grid[[1]]+a=0` therefore s starts from 0 in definition `hR[s]` .

Comment: Thanks, Sir for the explanations.@AlexTrounev

Comment: Sir, I just ran the code. Density plot and plot3d is not working.@AlexTrounev

Comment: Ah, sorry, line with `U` definition has been added.

Comment: Thanks, I already took it from your previous program. @AlexTrounev