# Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation With Periodically Varying Function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, nonlinear, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve Equation. 42 from https://labsites.rochester.edu/agrawal/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/paper_2019_03.pdf
The equation I am trying to solve is a nonlinear Schrödinger equation
[image]

More details can be found from this paper https://labsites.rochester.edu/agrawal/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/paper_2019_03.pdf

[image]

Here I present my MATHEMATICA code

```
    a = 20;
    Cvalue = 0.45;
    qvalue = 100;
    Nvalue = Sqrt[Cvalue];
    Fvalue[ζ_] := 
      Cos[π*qvalue*ζ]^2 + Cvalue^2 Sin[π*qvalue*ζ]^2;
    eqs = {I D[u[ζ, τ], ζ] + 
         1/2 D[u[ζ, τ], {τ, 2}] + 
         Nvalue^2/
          Fvalue[ζ] Abs[u[ζ, τ]]^2 u[ζ, τ] == 
        0, u[0, τ] == 0.5 Sech[τ], u[ζ, -a] == 0, 
       u[ζ, a] == 
        0, (D[u[ζ, τ], τ] /. τ -> a) == 
        0, (D[u[ζ, τ], τ] /. τ -> -a) == 0};
    sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, 
       u, {τ, -a, a}, {ζ, 0, 
        500},(*Method\[Rule]{"MethodOfLines",
       "SpatialDiscretization"\[Rule]{"TensorProductGrid",
       "MinPoints"\[Rule]100,"MaxPoints"\[Rule]400,
       "DifferenceOrder"\[Rule]4}},MaxSteps\[Rule]10^6*)
       Method -> {"FixedStep", "StepSize" -> 0.1, 
         Method -> {CrankNicolson, MaxIterations -> 5}}];
    data1 = Table[sol[100, τ], {τ, -a, a}];
    data2 = Table[0.5 Sech[τ], {τ, -a, a}];
    (*Spectral Density Plot*)
    ListLinePlot[{10 Log10[
        Abs[Fourier[data1]]^2/Abs[Fourier[{sol[100, 0]}][[1]]]^2], 
      10 Log10[Abs[Fourier[data2]]^2/Abs[Fourier[{0.5 Sech[0]}][[1]]]^2]},
      Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
    
    Plot[{10 Log10[Abs[sol[100, τ]]^2/Abs[sol[100, 0]]^2], 
      10 Log10[(0.5 Sech[τ])^2/(0.5 Sech[0])^2]}, {τ, -a, a}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, -60}}, 
     Frame -> True](*Relative Power Plot*)
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: There is no method called `CrankNicolson` ?

Comment: I am unable to generate the figures. If I take the commented method (not Crank Nicolson one) it's giving different results.@ChrisK @Nasser

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Did you generate Figure 4 from the paper with Crank-Nicolson?

Comment: No Sir, I have tried both the method Crank-Nicolson and the commented method in my posted program but non of them seems to even close to the desired Figure 4 though it has some resemblance.@AlexTrounev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in the paper Self-imaging in multimode graded-index fibers and its impact on the nonlinear phenomena by Govind P. Agrawal. With initial condition $u(0,\tau)=Sech(\tau)$ this problem can be solved with using method of lines. To demonstrate method of lines as it is we define `grid`, vector `varu[t]` and differentiation matrix `mat`, and then solve system of ODEs as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 20; grid = Range[-a, a, 1/10]; nn = Length[grid]; 
varu[t_] := Table[u[i][t], {i, nn}]; var = 
 Table[u[i], {i, 2, nn - 1}]; fddf = 
 NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], grid, 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]; mat = fddf@"DifferentiationMatrix"; du2 = 
 mat . varu[t];
Cvalue = .45;
qvalue = 100;
Nvalue = Sqrt[Cvalue];
Fvalue[t_] := Cos[\[Pi]*qvalue*t]^2 + Cvalue^2 Sin[\[Pi]*qvalue*t]^2;
eqs = Table[
  I D[u[i][t], t] + 1/2 du2[[i]] + 
    Nvalue^2/Fvalue[t] Abs[u[i][t]]^2 u[i][t] == 0, {i, 2, 
   nn - 1}]; ic = Table[u[i][0] == Sech[grid[[i]]], {i, 2, nn - 1}]; 
u[1][t_] := 0; u[nn][t_] := 0;

sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, 0, 100}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

Visualization
(*Spectral Density Plot*)

```
data1 = varu[100] /. sol[[1]]; sd1 = Abs[Fourier[data1]]^2; m1 = 
 Min[sd1];
data2 = Table[ Sech[grid[[i]]], {i, nn}]; sd2 = 
 Abs[Fourier[data2]]^2; m2 = Min[sd2];
n2 = Round[nn/2]; ListLinePlot[-{10 Log10[sd1/m1], 10 Log10[sd2/m2]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-50, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

(*Relative Power Plot*)

```
[{10 Log10[(Abs[varu[100]]/Abs[u[n2][100]])^2] /. 
   sol[[1]], 10 Log10[(Sech[grid])^2/( Sech[0])^2]}, 
 PlotRange -> {-80, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Function `Abs[u[ζ, τ]]`

```
lst = Table[{{t, grid[[i]]}, Abs[u[i][t]] /. sol[[1]]}, {t, 0, 
   100, .5}, {i, nn}]; U = Interpolation[Flatten[lst, 1]];

Plot3D[U[t, x], {t, 0, 100}, {x, -a, a}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", AxesLabel -> {\[Zeta], \[Tau]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks, Sir.  Can you tell me what was going wrong with my code? and how you chose a method so that you can get the desire. As you have answered my previously posted questions as well and every time you have chosen a different method including this one. @AlexTrounev

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Nothing wrong with your code, but we can't use method of lines implemented in `NDSolve` since we have to integrate equation with highly oscillating function `Fvalue` with about 10^4 periods on `{ζ, 0, 100}` (why do you try 500?) . Even with 30 points for every period we need more then $3\times 10^{5}$ steps (actually about 10^6). With `NDSolve` we can handle  system of ODEs with using 10^6 steps, but not PDE with using option `"MaxPoints"->10^6`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried 500 just to see the effect of length. When I ran my code I got different wavefunctions depending on different lengths. If I make the oscillating field to be 1, i.e. Fvalue=1, can then be my code useful? how can I verify? Where can I read about these tricky differences while choosing a method before using it in MATHEMATICA?@AlexTrounev

Comment: @ArghaDebnath On this forum we  discus many typical problem including this one. If you have any question we can  try to give answer. Is it your topic  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/267833/solving-integro-differential-equation-with-dirac-delta-term-for-dynamical-analys ?

Comment: Yes sir.@AlexTrounev  I mainly try to solve nonlinear differential equations.

Comment: Sir, can you tell me how much time the program is taking to give any result? For me every time I ran the code my PC froze. I am using MATHEMATICA 11.2@AlexTrounev

Comment: For space in range 1/5 it's giving instant result though for qvalue=10

Comment: Sorry, I can't test code with v.11.2 to check the problem you have. I run Mathematica vv. 12.2-13.01. In v.13.01 code takes 175 s and about 11Gb memory. If you have less memory it could be a problem.

Comment: Ok I think for my case Memory is a problem. Thanks @AlexTrounev